# K2 Category Filter Extension freezes after selection and filter

Tags: k2, content-filtering, joomla-3.7, php7

Just need a little bit of help with this extension: https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/filter-for-k2/

Basically it is a dropdown filter for K2 articles. My problem is that after you make a selection it will filter and display the articles for that category but then the reset button stops working and the dropdown selector no longer drops down..

You can see it here: https://mcrlogs.com/mcr_group/index.php/divisions/flooring/case-studies

I am using Joomla! 3.7, PHP7 & MySQL 5.6.

I'm sure there is only a small javascript problem but I have no idea how to find it as I don't know javascript very well.

If anyone could help out I would highly appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: I can't see a reset button? All seems to be working now?

Comment: Yep the problem was with the css, issue resolved!

Comment: Great, if possible you should add an answer as it could help others in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out this was a css issue, the below css needs to be added to your Joomla! template css file.

```
div[id*=k2FilterContainer] {
clear: both;
}
```